# move all JSON files from a local directory to s3 using the CLI

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to move all JSON files from a given local directory to a remote S3 folder.

Following [the instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html), I've tried:

```
aws s3 mv /path/to/loca/dir/                    \
         s3://bucket-name/path/to/destination/  \
         --exclude "*"                          \
         --include "*.json"                     \
         --acl public-read                      \
         --cache-control                        \
         max-age=15,public
```

Even though there are 166 JSON files in `/path/to/loca/dir/`, the `aws s3 mv` command exits quietly and does not move any file.

**Any idea why doesn't the `mv` copy the JSON files to the bucket?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `--recursive` flag.

> When passed with the parameter --recursive, the mv command
>   recursively moves all objects under a specified prefix and bucket to a
>   specified directory.

```
aws s3 mv /path/to/loca/dir/ s3://bucket-name/path/to/destination/ --recursive
```